# how to create ,manipulate,display SQLite DB on BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry

how to create ,manipulate,display SQLite DB on BlackBerry

Comment: read this: http://today.java.net/article/2010/03/17/getting-started-java-and-sqlite-blackberry-os-50

Answer (score 0):

RIM has a guide on this - [Storing data in SQLite databases](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17952/Storing_data_in_SQLite_databases_1219769_11.jsp).